# Implementing R programs in hadoop System

Tags: r, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, mapper

I have written Mapper and Reducer programs using R language. I am using the Hadoop streaming utility to execute the R programs on hadoop. My constraint is that i need to input 2 text files to the mapper program. How to achieve it? Kindly assist at the earliest.

For single input, I am placing the input file in the HDFS and referring them using the stdin command.But how to achieve it for multiple input files

Answer (score 0):

If you specify multiple input files they both are streamed through stdin. Order of records is arbitrary. To figure out which one you are actually reading at a certain time you can call `Sys.getenv("map_input_file")`.

Comment: If  you are doing a join you could use the rmr2 package where these gory details are taken care of for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [great tutorial](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) teaching you how to use Hadoop Streaming in Python. However, the example in that tutorial is reading 3 books, in your case 2 files, from a directory by doing something like this:

```
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ 
bin/hadoop jar contrib/streaming/hadoop-*streaming*.jar \
-file /home/hduser/mapper.py    -mapper /home/hduser/mapper.py \
-file /home/hduser/reducer.py   -reducer /home/hduser/reducer.py \
-input /user/hduser/gutenberg/* -output /user/hduser/gutenberg-output
```

The

```
-input /user/hduser/guttenberg/*
```

Will read all the files in that HDFS folder and process it.

Hope this solves your problem.